# perl -- call method from hash

Tags: perl, hash, hashtable

I have a hash table of methods:

```
my %makefileMacroSimplifiers = (
    "or" =>         \&makefileSimplifyOr,
    "and" =>        \&makefileSimplifyAnd,
    "strip" =>      \&makefileSimplifyStrip,
);

sub makefileSimplifyStrip {
    my $self = shift;
    my $prefix = shift;
    my $paramsRef = shift;
...
}
```

where each method requires `$self`.  What I have is:

```
$makefileMacroSimplifiers{$macroName}->($self, $macroName.$ws1, \@parms);
```

This seems to work, but it seems a bit odd to me to explicitly pass in `$self` to a method.  Is there a better way of doing this, or is this considered a normal coding practice?  (I didn't find any better ways to do this on the web, but I thought I would ask in case I'm not using the right search criteria).

Comment: I think you have to pass `$self` yes. That is, if you are calling methods from another method within the same class. Usually you would have a blessed object reference when you call methods ( using the syntax `$obj->method( ... )` ) from outside the class itself, then you do not need to pass `$self`

Comment: You need to show the calling method. Where do `$macroName` and `$ws1` come from?

Comment: `$macroName` and `$ws1` are results of parsing the input file.   In this case, `$macroName` would be `strip`, and `$ws1` is the whitespace following `strip`.   (Ok, technically in a makefile, `strip` is a function rather than a macro, but I'm trying to keep the naming consistent with the C counterparts in the program).

Comment: Ok, thanks @HåkonHægland, the `$self` parameter works, so if it doesn't stick out as bad coding practice, I'll use that.

Comment: I would prefer to see `my $method = $makefileMacroSimplifiers{$macroName}` followed by `$self->$method( $macroName.$ws1, \@parms )`. Also note that the hash values may be method identifiers as simple strings instead of references to subroutines.

Comment: @simbabque: I was writing in response to the OP, who says that they are going to use "the `$self` parameter", which I take to mean the call as it appears in the question which isn't a method call at all. I wanted to clarify that `$self->$makefileMacroSimplifiers{$macroName}($macroName.$ws1, \@parms)` won't work, as the method must be a simple scalar, or a bareword. I would have written an answer myself if I had thought yours didn't suffice. I'm sorry if you feel I have subverted your solution; it wasn't my intention.

Comment: @Borodin not at all. It's a useful comment. I was just confused there for a moment. I was pretty sure that it wouldn't work for exactly the reason you gave, I just couldn't try without my computer. Your explanation it good. It should stay. I'll reference it in my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also call a code ref on an object. That way the thing on the left will be passed in.

```
my $coderef = sub { ... };
$self->$coderef(@args);
```

Using a hash element does not work like this.

> ```
>  $self->$dispatch{foo}(1, 2, 3); # BOOM
> ```

This is a syntax error. So you need to grab the code reference first. [Borodin also explains this above in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041336/perl-call-method-from-hash?noredirect=1#comment71264942_42041336).

```
my %dispatch = (
    foo => sub { print "@_" },
);

require HTTP::Request;
my $obj = HTTP::Request->new;
my $method = $dispatch{foo};
$obj->$method(1, 2, 3);
```

I've used HTTP::Request here as an example of an arbitrary class/object.

Comment: This might not work with the hash though. I'm not near a computer so I can't confirm right  now.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've updated my code to do things this way.   I appreciate the comments.